# changes isn't detected in angular 2

Tags: angular

I've the template in which the links changes according to the 'userId' variable.

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="../../public/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li>
        <a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active"></a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="userId"><a>Welcome {{userInfo.name}}</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="gallery" routerLinkActive="active">Gallery</a></li>
      <li *ngIf="userId"><a routerLink="upload" routerLinkActive="active">Upload</a></li>
      <li *ngIf="userId"><a routerLink="logout" routerLinkActive="active">Logout</a></li>
      <li *ngIf="! userId"><a routerLink="auth" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a></li>
      <li *ngIf="! userId"><a routerLink="auth" routerLinkActive="active">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And I've the component which has the service which gets the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SessionService } from '../session.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [SessionService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public userId = "";
  public userInfo = "";

  constructor(
    private sessionService: SessionService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = this.sessionService.getLoggedInUserId();
    if (this.userId !== null) {
      this.sessionService.getLoggedInUserDetails(this.userId).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.userInfo = data.data[0];
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

the changes of the service call is not detected at the html part. the links are shown according to the 'userId' variable.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by your `sessionService` but your question doesn't provide details to be sure.

You can try

```
  constructor(
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private zone:NgZone
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = this.sessionService.getLoggedInUserId();
    if (this.userId !== null) {
      this.sessionService.getLoggedInUserDetails(this.userId).subscribe(
        data => {
          zone.run() => {
            this.userInfo = data.data[0];
          });
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

If this solves the problem, then the service needs further investigation.

Comment: this thing didn't helped. like in react js changes in components also gets rendered to html part but in here the nav bar isn't changing. if i refresh the page then I gets to see the changes at the nav bar.

Comment: It is about `userInfo.name`, right? Do you get an error in the browser console?. Can you please try `{{userInfo?.name}}` instead? or `{{userInfo | json}}` and post a comment with the results.

Comment: no its with userId. the scenario is that the getLoggedInUserId() funtion returns the id stored in the local storage. if the userId is there then the at the view side only three links will be shown.

Comment: So what do you get when you add `x{{userId}}y` to the tempalte (outside of the `*ngIf="userId"`?

Comment: nothing. But if i refresh the page I'm able to see the `userId`

Comment: What if you add `console.log(this.userId);` after `this.userId = this.sessionService.getLoggedInUserId();`? Do you get the userId printed to the console?